# Exact phrase match in elasticsearch on tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am implementing [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) on [tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) in my ruby on rails application.
I am doing pretty good so far with it. Now I want to retrieve results that matches exact values.
e.g. If there are two records with title "once upon" and "once upon a time",
"title: once upon" should return only one with title exactly "once upon"

Comment: Is doing a `regex` is a good idea?

Comment: I have no idea how this is done via tire but normally you should then index the title via keyword analyzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code:

```
Tire.search 'articles', do |search|
    search.size 100        #  Limit record
    search.from 0          #  start offeset

    # search.query.text keyword, :type => :phrase
    search.query do |query|
        query.text :_all, keyword, :type => :phrase
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it will helpful!

Comment: Why are you using here ``type: :phrase`` ??

Comment: query.text is deprecated! Use query.match now.

Comment: Phrase type searches the documents as if the keyword given is a phrase. However, it doesn't satisfy what the OP is asking for exactly.